# javafx desktop app xml operations

Tags: xml, javafx

I have one javafx desktop app to be prepared which needs some xml operations like create xml, insert - retrieve data from xml, etc. 
Which is the best way/api to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt, the Java api you would use for that, as JavaFX solely focus on UI generation, and not on general operations.

**EDIT**

My best guess, were your files small, is to use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/), as it is a simple yet powerful Java XML Api.